# Number as sum/difference of three squares

Tags: arithmetic

I have a puzzling question about this statement : 
consider four numbers $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb N$, $d\ \notin \Bbb N^2$, is it possible to state that this relation : $d=a^2 + b^2 -c^2$ is always true ? So that it is possible to write that number $d$ in that way ?

(please note the sign **minus** before the $c^2$)

Thanks guys !

Comment: What do you mean?  "Given three numbers $a,b,c,d$... " - but that's four numbers.  What is given, what is not?

Comment: Excuse me, i try to edit the main post but I cannot find the edit button.
The FOUR numbers a,c,b,d are NOT given

Comment: $$d = (d+1)^2 + \left(\frac{d(d+1)}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{d(d+1)}{2} + 1\right)^2$$

Comment: Another approach: If $d$ is odd, it can be written as $b^2 - c^2$. If $d$ is even, then $ d - 1$ is odd.

Comment: Look for the [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3570553/edit) button just to the left of your name below the question